# Deploy Application iOS not starting in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to create an app in Xamarin. On the Android side everything works fine. However when I deploy ios the app doesn't launch. It doesn't give an error or anything, I just get a response like this. I'm a bit confused about it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Application it automatically stops. I don't know how to solve it. Ask for help. Thanks

Comment: So is your application uploaded? Can you execute it without debugging? Have you tried a physical device and an emulator?

Comment: Have you tried a physical device and an emulator?--> Yes, i deploy local device. Yes, I'm all doing well

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Upgrade your visual studio to the latest and check the references in the project , please check the similar thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/412519/what-does-this-mean-and-how-to-fix-it-xamarinios-u.html.

Comment: Thanks, I made the post more clear here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463009/the-app-has-been-terminated-ios-in-xamarin) , I consulted you, however it doesn't work

Comment: Ok , let's move to focus on that thread.