# The app has been terminated iOS in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433986/deploy-application-ios-not-starting-in-xamarin), but this time I will create a new question which is more clear about the problem I had and of course I haven't solved the problem.

I am building application on Xamarin. Note the Android app works fine. I have this problem when I build iOS app on Iphone (iphone 11 promax) device I connect via USB port. iOS Version on Physical Iphone: 14.7.1

**Problem 1:**

```
Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous build version of your project.Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.
```

I tried rebuilding and restarting, I got **Problem 2**

**Problem 2:**

```
2021-10-06 16:15:30.684 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

2021-10-06 16:15:30.681 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41344] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 6
2021-10-06 16:15:30.684 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41344] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
2021-10-06 16:15:31.894 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B83579E-6A33-439A-B6C4-573479613557/Documents/Venus.iOS.content

Thread started:  #3
2021-10-06 16:15:31.910 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Forms app path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B83579E-6A33-439A-B6C4-573479613557/Documents/Venus.iOS.content/Venus.iOS.exe

2021-10-06 16:15:31.912 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Venus' (culture: '')
2021-10-06 16:15:31.912 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Venus' (culture: '')

2021-10-06 16:15:31.917 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2021-10-06 16:15:31.917 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B83579E-6A33-439A-B6C4-573479613557/Documents/Venus.iOS.content/Venus.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B83579E-6A33-439A-B6C4-573479613557/Documents/Venus.iOS.content/Venus.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B83579E-6A33-439A-B6C4-573479613557/Documents/Venus.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
2021-10-06 16:15:31.967 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[434:41340] Xamarin.Forms AppDelegate name: AppDelegate


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
    0x10270009c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1026f6bdc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

us.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x10289e018 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x102706c70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1027b37a8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1027b8b54 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x1026eb7d8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x10289c0f8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main
    0x1026b2944 - /private/var/containers/Bun
    0x1027039b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1d093c29c - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1997c5660 - /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1849133b4 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x184903948 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x184913f30 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1849139c0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x184915928 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x184906ecc - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1028aa4d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x1028a8b94 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x10289fa88 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Ven
0c>
      at System.Action`1:invoke_void_T <0x0007c>
      at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application:LoadFrameworks <0x00072>
      at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application:Run <0x0018e>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x0005a>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
=================================================================

dle/Application/72194A0D-FD29-4EC6-A65A-606D7E245A44/Venus.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x184901cf8 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x10be33e80):0x10be33e70  f6 57 c3 a8 c0 03 5f d6 00 08 40 f9 c0 03 5f d6  .W...._...@..._.
0x10be33e80  f4 4f be a9 fd 7b 01 a9 fd 43 00 91 1f 20 03 d5  .O...{...C... ..
0x10be33e90  48 0d 02 58 00 01 40 fd 1f 20 03 d5 61 18 01 5c  H..X..@.. ..a..\
0x10be33ea0  00 20 61 1e 65 02 00 54 20 e8 01 30 1f 20 03 d5  . a.e..T ..0. ..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:_dlopen <0x00026>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at <>c:<Main>b__0_0 <0x000
The app has been terminated.
```

I have consulted many articles, in which I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/412519/what-does-this-mean-and-how-to-fix-it-xamarinios-u.html) with similar problem

I have implemented the solutions:

- Update Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.3
- Delete the: folder: bin, obj in the .ios project and rebuild the project.

However it still gives the same error as **problem 2** I stated above. How can I handle it. I've spent 4 days now and haven't solved it yet. Please solution. Thanks very much

Comment: When you normal just clean build the iOS app does it build? If yes then are you sure the provisioning profiles and certificates are configured correctly on your MAC?

Comment: Oh No, I don't use Mac, I use Windows. I try to build iOS apps via a physical Iphone device that I connect via USB

Comment: But you cannot run an iOS app without a mac!? More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos

Comment: Haizzzz, so is this a must for me to have a Mac?

Comment: Yes a 100% you cant do anything without it

Comment: That is incorrect. I am developing a Xamarin Forms app on Win10 machine and I regularly debug it directly on my iPhone.

Comment: This link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/404442/xamarin-forms-app-fails-to-run-debug-on-physical-i.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hot restart is not officially supported by Apple. As it depends on the state of Apple's tools it may break at any time. Right now it doesn't work with iOS 15: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12915